# php smtp authentication issue

Tags: php, smtp

This is mail1.php page, when I started to use I receive authentication error.

```
  <?php 

 include 'class.phpmailer.php';
 $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
 $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
 $mail->Port = 465; // 587
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
 $mail->Username = "behzatdeniz82@gmail.com";
 $mail->Password = "**********"; //Don't reveal password with others
 $mail->SetFrom("behzatdeniz82@gmail.com");
 $mail->Subject = "Test";
 $mail->Body = "hello";
 $mail->AddAddress("behzatdeniz99@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send())
 {
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Message has been sent";
 }
?>
```

I received below error message. I changed port numbers and try again, but no result. Can anyone help me ?

```
 SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command 
 first. 8sm65292722eeq.15 - gsmtp SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: 
 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

to enable SSL.

Comment: I did as you said but now received this error. " SMTP -> ERROR: STARTTLS not accepted from server: 454 5.5.1 STARTTLS may not be repeated. d6sm18655050wic.9 - gsmtp 
Language string failed to load: tls Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: tls "

Comment: Yoy may also add: _$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';_ Do you have a SSL certificate on your server?

Comment: Yes, I Have ssl cert. It works now: $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "myname"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password